# Print text file line by line in an Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read a text file line by line and then print it to an excel sheet line by line

Here is what I have so far

```
for x in ABC:
    print(f"{x}:")
    sheet1[cellLocLastRow('A')] = f"{x}:"
    try:
        with open(f"./{x}/Log.txt") as f:
            textRead= (f.read())
            print(textRead)
            sheet1[cellLocLastRow('A')] = textRead
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
        sheet1[cellLocLastRow('A')] = "File does not exist"
```

It prints it out the text file to the excel sheet but all in one row like this
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCLzE.png)

But I would like my text file to be printed out like this
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH8FY.png)

If you were wondering why I am using `[cellLocLastRow('A')]` , I am using that instead of a `[A17]` because I am printing out unknown lengths of documents into an excel sheet and so it counts the rows.

```
def cellLocLastRow(colChar):
    global lastRow
    curRow = lastRow
    lastRow += 1
    return cellLoc(colChar, curRow)
```

The text file format is as follows:

```
TestName: TestName

TestName: Info::Info::Info::Info::f###::##.#ns
Total Errors: #

TestName: Info::Info::Info::Info::f###::##.#ns
Total Errors: #

TestName: Info::Info::Info::Info::f###::##.#ns
Total Errors: #
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `f.readlines()` method?

```
with open(text, 'r') as f: 
content1 = f.readlines()
```

This script will return a list with all file's lines, then you can do whatever you want comfortably.

Comment: I get the following errors: ValueError: Cannot convert [] to Excel

Comment: I updated it to readlines() only without strip. it should be successful, its python built-in function. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readline.asp

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty easy with pylightxl

> pip install pylightxl

```
lines = []
with open(“textfile.txt”) as f:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    lines.append(line)


import pylightxl as xl

db = xl.Database()

db.add_ws("Sheet1", {})

for i, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
    db.ws("Sheet1").update_index(i, 1,line)

xl.writexl(db, “output.xlsx”)
```